# How do I overlap a table on java

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

I want two or more tables to be shown/overlapping each other.

Currently using netbeans

I'm using jFrame form so not manually creating a layout.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible using `null` as the layout manager ([absolute positioning](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html)). You might also want to place each table in a separate [JInternalFrame](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html) container as this will allow you to move and resize the tables freely withing the main window.